Kotlin Multiplatform - No iOS Configuration or Devices detected
I'm trying to start with Kotlin Multiplatform, so I've installed the plugin and created the default project.
Once everything is set, I can run it on Android, but I don't have an iOSApp configuration. When I try to create it, I realize that the Execution targetlist is empty, it doesn't detect the simulator/real devices on my mac.

I've updated everything: The plugin, Android Studio, Cocoapods, Java, Ruby, etc... Relaunched my Mac, deleted and re-created the project, nothing works.
I'm just trying to run it on iOS and I feel like something is missing, here's my configuration.


If you have any idea of what could work, it would be nice!

Did you try to run the ios app in the xcode? see if the project runs. just open the yourdemo/iosApp/iosapp.xcodeproject  folder inside the xcode and then run it

@ShadmanAdman I am facing the same issue and yes I've tried opening the ios part on the code and it's building fine there, but we have to build the updated code from android studio from which the ios devices are not detected, furthermore in the code -> devices and simulatore, I only have iPhone 14 simulator and no other devices watches etc which could potentially interfere

Did you solve it ?

You might have to run XCode one more time and make sure you were able to launch simulators from xcode. Then restart your android studio and you should be able to see the execution targets.

I've met the same issue, and solve it by upgrading Xcode to 15, click here for more details.
